# What is it this Time?

Tags: cipher, knowledge, time

Most clocks tell the time, but some are for letters.

```
03:00 11:53 07:45 06:07 06:29 07:30 09:15 11:53 06:29 09:45 06:15 06:29 
04:45 07:52 07:15 09:00 08:11 07:52 05:53 07:52 11:53 02:53 06:29 07:52
04:45 06:29 07:30 06:29 09:00 10:08 04:15 04:15 06:07 06:29 09:45 06:15
06:29 05:53 08:53 07:15 09:00 08:11 06:07 01:23 07:53 11:53 02:53 06:29
```

The answer is an English sentence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is the solution:

> The hands of the clock encode letters with the flag semaphore system resulting in the sentence "The art of simplicity is a puzzle of complexity"! ;)

This is a nice idea, but

> it is easy to also crack it by any other method for monoalphabetic substitution cipher

Thank you for this nice riddle!

Comment: Easy? Not with the typo in ”puzze” and the silly 03:00 in the beginning it isn’t :-)

Comment: @Bass The 03:00 means "letters are following" (as opposed to numbers). And I completely  overread the typo in "puzze" ;))

Comment: Nice, I was wondering if it was difficult; I always underestimate the Puzzling folks.  Can't believe I made a typo, I double-checked it. Oh well.